# Xcode 3.1 localization: If I change the interface, do I need to change this for each localization?

Tags: xcode, localization, macos

I've just made an application in Xcode, and I'm trying to localize it. I right-clicked (Ctrl-clicked) my .xib and clicked 'Get info'. I added Dutch to the list of localizations and Xcode made copied my .xib file. Do I need to change the .xib file for every single localization when I make an adjustment? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ibtool`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html) to apply incremental changes to the localised XIBs without messing up any of the translation, or existing layout changes you've made to accommodate the different text lengths. Look particularly for the `--localize-incremental` option.